# WebRTC "OperationError" when sending a file from iPhone to PC

Tags: webrtc

I have utilized the [simple-peer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer) library, which is a convenient wrapper for the [WebRTC API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API). My goal is to create a web page that displays all available devices currently connected to the website and sharing the same Wi-Fi network. Additionally, I want to enable file transfer functionality between these devices.

To facilitate the communication, I have implemented a signaling server responsible for exchanging ICE Candidates and the Offer/Answer process. The connection works flawlessly as I have successfully tested file transfers between open tabs on the same device and between different computers on the same network.

However, I have encountered an issue when attempting to send files from a mobile device (iPhone 13) to a laptop on the same network. In this scenario, I receive an "Operation Error" and the connection closes without any specific details. Strangely, when sending simple text messages `("Hello world")`, the communication works perfectly between the mobile device and the laptop.

**This only happens when sending from phone to PC, not the opposite. Computer to phone works perfectly.**

Not sure what code to show because it can't really help, besides this piece of code that is the actual file transfer:

```
  public sendFile(file: any) {
    try {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const data: any = reader.result;
        this.peer?.send(data);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR');
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

What could be the issue, is that something to do with default file size limit or something?

EDIT: Seems like it has to do with file size. Something over 100kb or so doesn't work.